# Why doesn't Wolverine die when he loses his ability to heal?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

In [The Wolverine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/), Viper suppresses Logan's healing power by introducing some kind of bug into his body. This affects the healing power of Wolverine and slows him down considerably.

After this he even takes lots of bullet shots, blade cuts, got thrown down on the floor from a considerable height. He does get injured, but with out his healing power.

Shouldn't he have been dead until some one (probably in postmortem) removes that bug?

Comment: Good question! One that probably deserves the attention of scifi and/or comic readers and their wealth of greater X-Men knowledge. Do questions like this cross-posted in those forums by admin suggestion, etc.?

Comment: @rbsite - Not necessarily crossposted, but they can be migrated. It probably won't be migrated though, since it fits here as well.

Comment: @rbsite No, deliberate cross-posting is highly discouraged and would divide the answers. Likewise, as *JohnP* says, migration of on-topic stuff by moderator decision only is also invalid. The attention of avid movie watchers has to suffice for now (at least if *Ashutosh* doesn't decide to propose migration himself, which I hope he doesn't). Unfortunately the means for directly sharing links to certain questions with other sites are rather scarce either (but would maybe not be of too much use in general anyway).

Comment: You say "suppresses Logan's healing power" which I think is key to your question. I thought of his power as being suppressed, but not eliminated. To me, it was just brought down to a *normal* healing ability and not a *super-human* healing ability, taking away his super-human status.

Comment: @Paulster2 exactly thats my question it is almost very rare for normal human being to survive all that lethal injuries

Comment: Almost, but not unheard of. If anything would have killed him, it would have been when he extracted the "bug" (whatever it was) out of himself. That would take *super-human* abilities in and of itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most of Logan's death-defying experiences are excused by his regenerative ability or the added strength of his adamantium skeleton (added in 1979 per the [movie canon timeline](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline)). When one is inactive, the other picks up the slack, so to speak.

In The Wolverine I believe the audience is meant to understand that his skeleton is deflecting and/or softening impacts. Other movie tropes are also at work, of course, such as the [super strong protagonist who can survive lethal injury](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnlyAFleshWound).

The bug itself is a trope, the [symbiote](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheSymbiote), which even in destructive cases usually wants the host to live as long as possible for maximum benefit. I can only speculate as to whether the bug somehow kept Logan alive or allowed traces of his regeneration to become active when he would have otherwise died, or if keeping him alive until he was on the operation table was in Viper's interest, etc., but given Viper's revealed plans to extract and harness Logan's ability itself, it seems reasonable.

Comment: Well, even more than a "trope", a symbiote (or rather parasite) is a known biological concept, which you don't really need a TVTropes link to understand or set in relation to the movie. But still good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I got to this answer in a roundabout way trying to relate the nebulous science of things like the surveillance bug in The Matrix. In re-reading that wasn't really a valid connection and I trimmed it, but failed to show how I got from that to thinking of "A can attach to B and all consequences make sense" and going with symbiote. In the process I forgot all about real world parasites and things. ^^;

Answer (score 3):

Also don't forget the adamantium in his body its not normal human bone it's the adamantium (the only thing that it can fight against it is Captain America's shield and adamantium itself). Hence he might have lost his healing ability but his bones are strong as hell and while fighting that big robot guy he was very careful (watch the scenes closely).

Comment: You can still die from injuries, even if your skeleton is completely unharmed. The adamantium alone can't explain this.

Comment: you sure can die from injuries, but his healing was not completely destroyed it was just down. loss of lot of blood kills you but like i mentioned he did not suffer any internal fractures[because of his bone structure] which helped him to bleed less. the fall just made him unconscious and gave him a concoction . which is very common